# Converting two lists into dynamic nested dict then to JSON

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have to go through a list of "colors":

```
list1 = ["red","green","other"]
```

for each one I need to go through a list of possible matches for each one:

```
list2 = ["cherries","rasperries","guava","apple","watermelon","grapes","banana"]
```

if the criteria of the item of list2 is good, then I'd need to create a dict to then write the output to JSON file.

```
for x in list1:
  print x
  for y in list2:
    if y == criteria:
      myDict = {'list1-item': 'fruit1':'apple'}
```

my expected output would be something like:

```
data = {'red': {'fruit1': 'cherries', 'fruit2': 'rasperries', 'fruit3': 'guava'},
      'green': {'fruit1': 'apple'},
      'other': {'fruit1': 'watermelon', 'fruit2': 'grapes', 'fruit3': 'banana'}}
```

Writing to JSON

```
with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Not really familiar with building a dynamic dictionary as needed.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. You have multiple steps here, try to solve each one individually and give a [mcve] if you get stuck. What you've posted so far isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe, I don't understand what is the relation between **y** that is an element from the list2 with the criteria.  I suppose that the element of the list2 have some attributes to apply some criteria over this attributes but the previous idea is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

```
import pprint
from random import randint
list1 = ["red", "green", "other"]
list2 = ["cherries", "rasperries", "guava", "apple", "watermelon", "grapes", "banana"]


myDict = dict()
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if 1 == randint(0, 1):
            l = len(myDict.get(x, []))
            if l == 0:
                myDict[x] = dict()
            myDict[x]['fruit{}'.format(l)] = y

pprint.pprint(myDict)
```